# How can I do a re-authentification on approval in a Sharepoint approval workflow?

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

The security guy ask me to make a step where the approver need to re-authenticate when he approve the list item. All of the other part of the workflow is done except this one. The best solution would be to use the built in log-in of Sharepoint, but I don't know how to do that.
I want to point out that I'm doing this workflow with visual studio 2008 and deploy to WSS 3.0.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Havent done this myself, but a quick googling around led to these:

- [Credential Management with the .NET
  Framework 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480470.aspx)
- [How to show authentication dialog in
  C# .Net 3.5 SP1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596161/how-to-show-authentication-dialog-in-c-net-3-5-sp1)

Maybe those topics can lead you to the right path.

Comment: I will probably resort to this option. Sharepoint workflow with a custom login page.

Answer (score 1):

You should clarify what you need, as what you request is how Sharepoint already works.

In order for the approver to approve an item he has to log-in to Sharepoint, using the built-in mechanisms. If you are using windows authentication (the default) instead of FBA, the user is logged in automatically using his Windows credentials. So there is no need (or point) for the user to re-authenticate - Sharepoint already knows who he is.

The only case where there might be an issue is when both requestor and approver have to use the same computer. Unless the requestor also has approval right, he will not be able to approve the request.

Are you perhaps concerned that a user with approval right may try to approve his own request? In this case you can prevent him from doing so by granting him read-only right to his request, ie removing the update right.

Comment: The authentification is already done like you said with the windows credential, but the goal to ask for a re-authentification is to make sure that the user in front of the computer is really the good one. I know that it's a overhead(I said the same thing the client) but he want to know if it can be done.

Comment: If the security guy did his job right, then there should be an idle lockout policy in place, no? Sharepoint is the wrong place to fix domain policy issues. If you really want to make Sharepoint more secure than the entire window domain, you can display a custom form for the approval task that requests username/password and have your workflow activity validate them. Be prepared to have a lot of annoyed end users though. IT People like Sharepoint because they don't have to remember a separate login for it. This requirement essentially disables the built-in integrated authentication