# How to show Windows Login Dialog?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, winapi

How to display Windows Login dialog box whitin a windows **WPF** application?

[image: Login dialog box]

Comment: It's a duplicate question, try to search before submiting new questions. This results in fewer question, richer content. tnx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks similar to [Show Authentication dialog in C# for windows Vista/7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134882/show-authentication-dialog-in-c-sharp-for-windows-vista-7)

[CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375178)

Answer (score 10):

I wrote a helper class for this. It shows the "XP Style" login dialog, not the one you're showing in your screenshot, but you'll be able to go on from there to show the "new" dialog, too:

```
public static class UserHelper
{
    [Flags]
    public enum CREDUI_FLAGS
    {
        INCORRECT_PASSWORD = 0x1,
        DO_NOT_PERSIST = 0x2,
        REQUEST_ADMINISTRATOR = 0x4,
        EXCLUDE_CERTIFICATES = 0x8,
        REQUIRE_CERTIFICATE = 0x10,
        SHOW_SAVE_CHECK_BOX = 0x40,
        ALWAYS_SHOW_UI = 0x80,
        REQUIRE_SMARTCARD = 0x100,
        PASSWORD_ONLY_OK = 0x200,
        VALIDATE_USERNAME = 0x400,
        COMPLETE_USERNAME = 0x800,
        PERSIST = 0x1000,
        SERVER_CREDENTIAL = 0x4000,
        EXPECT_CONFIRMATION = 0x20000,
        GENERIC_CREDENTIALS = 0x40000,
        USERNAME_TARGET_CREDENTIALS = 0x80000,
        KEEP_USERNAME = 0x100000,
    }


    public enum CredUIReturnCodes
    {
        NO_ERROR = 0,
        ERROR_CANCELLED = 1223,
        ERROR_NO_SUCH_LOGON_SESSION = 1312,
        ERROR_NOT_FOUND = 1168,
        ERROR_INVALID_ACCOUNT_NAME = 1315,
        ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 122,
        ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER = 87,
        ERROR_INVALID_FLAGS = 1004,
        ERROR_BAD_ARGUMENTS = 160
    }


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct CREDUI_INFO
    {
        public int cbSize;
        public IntPtr hwndParent;
        public string pszMessageText;
        public string pszCaptionText;
        public IntPtr hbmBanner;
    }


    [DllImport("credui", EntryPoint = "CredUIPromptForCredentialsW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern CredUIReturnCodes CredUIPromptForCredentials(ref CREDUI_INFO creditUR, string targetName, IntPtr reserved1, int iError, StringBuilder userName, int maxUserName, StringBuilder password, int maxPassword, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] ref bool pfSave, CREDUI_FLAGS flags);

    [DllImport("credui", EntryPoint = "CredUIParseUserNameW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern CredUIReturnCodes CredUIParseUserName(string userName, StringBuilder user, int userMaxChars, StringBuilder domain, int domainMaxChars);

    const int MAX_USER_NAME = 100;
    const int MAX_PASSWORD = 100;
    const int MAX_DOMAIN = 100;

    public static CredUIReturnCodes PromptForCredentials(System.Windows.Window parentWindow, ref CREDUI_INFO creditUI, string targetName, int netError, out string domainName, out string userName, out string password, ref bool save, CREDUI_FLAGS flags)
    {
        userName = String.Empty;
        domainName = String.Empty;
        password = String.Empty;

        creditUI.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(creditUI);
        creditUI.hwndParent = new WindowInteropHelper(parentWindow).Handle;

        StringBuilder user = new StringBuilder(MAX_USER_NAME);
        StringBuilder pwd = new StringBuilder(MAX_PASSWORD);
        CredUIReturnCodes result = CredUIPromptForCredentials(ref creditUI, targetName, IntPtr.Zero, netError, user, MAX_USER_NAME, pwd, MAX_PASSWORD, ref save, flags);
        if (result == CredUIReturnCodes.NO_ERROR)
        {
            string tempUserName = user.ToString();
            string tempPassword = pwd.ToString();

            StringBuilder userBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder domainBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            CredUIReturnCodes returnCode = CredUIParseUserName(tempUserName, userBuilder, int.MaxValue, domainBuilder, int.MaxValue);
            switch (returnCode)
            {
                case CredUIReturnCodes.NO_ERROR:
                    userName = userBuilder.ToString();
                    domainName = domainBuilder.ToString();
                    password = tempPassword;
                    return returnCode;

                case CredUIReturnCodes.ERROR_INVALID_ACCOUNT_NAME:
                    userName = tempUserName;
                    domainName = String.Empty;
                    password = tempPassword;
                    return returnCode;

                default:
                    return returnCode;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

I invoke this using:

```
UserHelper.CREDUI_INFO info = new UserHelper.CREDUI_INFO();
info.pszCaptionText = host;
info.pszMessageText = "Please log in:";

UserHelper.CREDUI_FLAGS flags = UserHelper.CREDUI_FLAGS.GENERIC_CREDENTIALS |
                                UserHelper.CREDUI_FLAGS.ALWAYS_SHOW_UI |
                                UserHelper.CREDUI_FLAGS.DO_NOT_PERSIST |                                               
                                UserHelper.CREDUI_FLAGS.VALIDATE_USERNAME |
                                UserHelper.CREDUI_FLAGS.INCORRECT_PASSWORD;

UserHelper.CredUIReturnCodes result = UserHelper.PromptForCredentials(this, ref info, host, 0, out domainName, out userName, out password, ref saveSettings, flags);
```