# Is it possible to show credentials box for WindowsIdentity?

Tags: asp.net, .net, active-directory, windows-identity

Sometimes the WindowsIdentity can't find the user. Am I able to show a credentials box (screen where the user type login and password) to WindowsIdentity identify the user?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I found the solution:

[Show Authentication dialog in C# for windows Vista/7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134882/show-authentication-dialog-in-c-sharp-for-windows-vista-7)

I was searching for the wrong keyword. The correct keyword is "authentication dialog".